# Why are pro-objects in the category of finite groups equivalent to group objects in the category of profinite sets?

Tags: category-theory

https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/profinite%20group

The nlab gives two definitions of profinite group: either as pro-objects in the category of finite groups, OR as group objects in the category of profinite sets. Why are these two definitions equivalent? I can't find any purely categorical proof of this equivalence, but I am sure one exists.

Comment: I don't believe an abstract nonsense proof exists. In general we can expect that pro(finite algebras) are strictly less general than (profinite) algebras. For example, consider the case of real vector spaces instead of groups.

Comment: You might be interested in Section VI.2 ("profinite sets and algebras") in the book *Stone spaces* by Johnstone.